# ¿Como puedo hacer una sentencia que me diga cual Carrera tiene mayor y menor cantidad de Estudiantes?

Tags: mysql

Ejemplo:

Tengo 4 carreras cualquiera.

```
select id_Carrera,count(*) as Cantidad_Estudiantes from Estudiante
group by id_Carrera;
```

Este código me cuenta la cantidad de estudiante que hay en cada Carrera, pero quisiera saber en especifico cuál es la que tiene mas y cuál tiene menos.

¿Cómo podría usar la función `MAX()` y el `MIN()` dentro de esa sentencia para que me salga lo deseado? ¿Alguna recomendación por favor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aunque parezca sencilla, en `SQL` ésta es una de las consultas más difíciles de implementar:

```
SELECT id_Carrera,COUNT(*) Cantidad_Estudiantes, 'MAX'
  FROM Estudiante GROUP BY id_Carrera
  HAVING Cantidad_Estudiantes=(
    SELECT MAX(Cantidad_Estudiantes) FROM (
        SELECT id_Carrera,COUNT(*) Cantidad_Estudiantes
          FROM Estudiante GROUP BY id_Carrera  
      ) corredores_por_carrera
)
  UNION
SELECT id_Carrera,COUNT(*) Cantidad_Estudiantes, 'MIN'
  FROM Estudiante GROUP BY id_Carrera
  HAVING Cantidad_Estudiantes=(
    SELECT MIN(Cantidad_Estudiantes) FROM (
        SELECT id_Carrera,COUNT(*) Cantidad_Estudiantes
          FROM Estudiante GROUP BY id_Carrera  
      ) corredores_por_carrera
);
```

Una de las primeras cosas que tenemos que saber sobre las consultas `SQL` es que realmente trabajan con ciertos operadores algebraicos. Nuestra lógica de programadores suele chocar con el `SQL` porque su funcionamiento es ligeramente diferente. Así como, para encontrar el máximo en un `array`, recorreríamos el `array` completo y, una vez localizado ese máximo, tendríamos también su índice; en `SQL` no va así, la función de `totales MAX(campo)` localiza el valor máximo de un campo, pero aún no sabemos a quién puede corresponder. De entrada, porque podría corresponder a más de uno. Para saber a quién corresponde, es necesario realizar una selección utilizando el `WHERE` (que tras un `GROUP BY` se implementa con un `HAVING`) en el que nos quedemos con los registros cuyo campo coincida con el valor máximo que antes hemos localizado.

Esta consulta es larga porque hacemos esta misma operación dos veces y, además, a partir de una subconsulta de agrupamiento pero, en esencia, si se entiende el concepto anterior, las otras operaciones son sencillas.

Para entender esto en profundidad, lo más recomendable es estudiar álgebra relacional, pues ayuda a entender la lógica que hay por detrás del `SQL`.

Dejad dudas en los comentarios e intentaré responderlas editando esta respuesta.

Comment: Excelente, es exactamente lo que necesitaba. Por favor explicame. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Espero que la explicación se entienda. El tema es complejo, pregunta todo lo que necesites.

Comment: Es `HAVING` equivalente de `WHERE` usándose el primero después de clausulas `GROUP BY` nunca había escuchado de esta claúsula hasta ahora.

Comment: Sí, es la misma operación algebraica. Sólo que, después de un GROUP BY, no se puede usar WHERE (teóricamente WHERE se aplica antes de los agrupamientos). Para no tener que hacer una subconsulta para poder meter el segundo WHERE, se implementó HAVING.

Comment: Excelente, ahora comprendo mejor. Me pondré a practicarlo y seguir investigando para dominarlo por completo. Muchas gracias amigos, fue muy importante sus aportes!

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas utilizar `min` y `max`, puedes jugar con `limit` y `order by` y no tener que utilizar `subqueries` que son bastante poco eficientes.

Te adjunto otra forma de lograr el mismo resultado pero más eficientemente:

```
select id_Carrera,count(*) as Cantidad_Estudiantes, 'Máximo'
from Estudiante
group by id_Carrera
order by Cantidad_Estudiantes desc
limit 1
UNION
select id_Carrera,count(*) as Cantidad_Estudiantes, 'Mínimo'
from Estudiante
group by id_Carrera
order by Cantidad_Estudiantes asc
limit 1;
```

Obtienes el máximo ordenando de mayor a menor y sacando el primer resultado y el mínimo ordenando de menor a mayor y sacando el primero también.

Comment: ¿Por qué motivo dices que las subquerys son poco eficientes? La forma más eficiente de optimizar una consulta es precisamente utilizando subconsultas proyectadas y seleccionadas, para transferir a la RAM del servidor la mínima cantidad de datos, con los que después realizar operaciones más complejas como productos o agrupamientos.

Comment: Con respecto al ORDER BY y el LIMIT, estoy de acuerdo contigo en que son muy fáciles de entender y la query SQL resultante es mucho más corta. Sin embargo, si queremos que la consulta se ejecute en el menor tiempo posible, en quien tenemos que pensar en el servidor que la procesará. Y no hace los cálcucos de forma muy distinta a como los haríamos manualmente. ¿Qué harías más rápido? ¿Ordenar todos los elementos de una lista para quedarte con el primero? ¿O buscar el número más alto o más bajo en ese misma lista?

Comment: ¿Ves que este último caso sólo tienes que darle una pasada a la lista? Ordenar es de las operaciones más costosas computacionalmente, de ahí que se deje siempre para el final y únicamente para la presentación de resultados.

Comment: Porque trabajo con mysql y he optimizado muchísimas consultas y generalmente, salvo casos puntuales, las subqueries  aumentan el tiempo de ejecución enormemente. He reducido queries de horas a segundos quitando subqueries. Cómo crees que obtiene mysql el máximo o el mínimo internamente, sobre todo de un group by, esto no es un dato almacenado como el count(*), mysql lo agrupa, luego lo ordena y obtiene el primer resultado y ese es el maximo, o el minimo. Estoy haciendo lo que hace mysql internamente directamente.

Comment: No dudo que simplificando consultas las hayas optimizado, totalmente de acuerdo. Depende de qué y para qué se hiciera la subconsulta, a veces se dan rodeos muy innecesarios. Pero, para buscar un máximo, ten por seguro que MySQL no ordena todos los elementos para quedarse con el mayor, sería tremendamente ineficiente. Para buscar el número mayor en una lista, no necesitas ordenar todos los números, sólo tienes que quedarte con el primero e ir sustituyéndolo por los que lo vayan superando del resto de la lista. Computacionalmente no tiene nada que ver.

Comment: Efectivamente tienes razón en que no lo ordena como tal, te agradezco la corrección al respecto ya que te aseguro que me va a servir más de una vez. No sé si borrar la respuesta o dejarla como opción más comprensible.

Comment: Déjala por favor, si funciona perfectamente. Además, como me acaba de comentar @gbianchi, si haces el ORDER BY sobre un campo indexado (que siempre está ordenado en memoria) es inmediato. Yo creo que estas contribuciones enriquecen un montón a la comunidad, te lo agradezco mucho

Comment: Lo dejo pues. Un placer debatir/aprender contigo.

Comment: Sus comentarios me han ayudado muchísimo, no sabia esas cosas. Muchas gracias amigos, son los mejores!